# How to send mail in node.js without providing credential(username and password)

Tags: node.js, nodemailer

I'm trying to send the mail using nodemailer without signing(without providing credential).

```
const nodemailer = require('nodemailer');

const smtpConfig = {
    host: 'Smtp.gmail.com',
    port: 587, //I've tried other port also. But nothing works.
    secure: false, // dont use SSL
    tls: {rejectUnauthorized: false} ,
    use_authentication: false,
};

const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport(smtpConfig);

const mailOptions = {
    from: "my-address@gmail.com",
    to: "reciever-address@gmail.com",
    subject: 'Hello ✔', // Subject line
    text: 'Hello world ', // plaintext body
    html: '<b>Hello world </b>' // html body
};

transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function(error, info){
    if(error){
        return console.log("we got an error",error);
    }
    console.log('Message sent: ' + info.response);
});
```

But this gives an error
Error: Mail command failed: 530-5.7.0 Authentication Required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gmail needs authentication.
The issue is not located in nodemailer ;)

Comment: So is there any other module for this ?